# PHP 'Who viewed my profile' page

Tags: php, database

I have a question regarding a page that I am currently working on.
It's called 'Who viewed my profile'. I already have a user system on my website and also a profile system, but I just need another page that will display people who viewed my profile.

So let's say I am 'user A', I am sharing some information on my profile. In the mean time, 'user B' and 'User C', views my profile details.

How can I fetch from the database - people/users that viewed a certain profile? This feature will be visible to me only or to 'user A'.

Comment: You have to save that information into the database when User B and User C visit the page.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea on how to actually structure this?

Answer (score 3):

I will suggest you to have another table called `profile_views` with 2 columns `profile_id` and 'guest_id', which are references to the `users` table

Comment: while you're at it, you could add a few other metrics to the tracking, like ip address, date/time, etc. even if you don't use them now, you may want to use them down the road!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why there is a need for another page for such content. The content is very tiny so why not put it in a DIV retrieving input from AJAX?

So lets say we have profile.php, just put in a hidden attribute there with the user id of the page. Now when a guest comes in, save in profile_views (I'm using from the tables "Haynar" gave above) the ID of the guest and the ID of the user from the hidden attribute and send an insert statement to the Database - MAKE SURE AND CHECK FIRST IF THAT TUPLE EXIST OR ELSE YOU WILL GET A UNIQUE CONSTRAINT ERROR.

Now when you come in your profile page, just code a simple ajax method to retrieve all the guest IDs and pull this data to populate the div. That way it's not in another page (which in my view is unnecessary) and you get exactly what you're looking for.

[image: Check this out, I used the same concept to display all the user currently logged into my system and just used a little div to display the results. I also used CSS so if lets say 20 uses are logged in, the div wont overflow but rather a scroll bar will appear on the div]

Check this out, I used the same concept to display all the user currently logged into my system and just used a little div to display the results. I also used CSS so if lets say 20 uses are logged in, the div wont overflow but rather a scroll bar will appear on the div

Hope this was helpful.

Edit: actually re-thinking, you don't even need to use AJAX here, could use normal PHP code to retrieve the data when the page is loading

Answer (score 0):

Also, to expand on haynar's answer, you should use caching for the look-up table (profile_views).

You're most likely want to retrieve the total profile views of a specific user and not to break down it by users, therefore you must use `SUM` / `COUNT` in your SQL, which is a costly SQL statement.

You should save this sum in the users table for example in a `profile_views` column, and update it from time to time, like once in an hour maybe.